# Cant do login paypal in ionic 3 project

Tags: paypal, ionic3, paypal-rest-sdk

I am integrating PayPal in ionic3 app, whenever I click on make payment it redirects to paypal site, there I enter username and password and each time it says "invalid username and/or password", but I am adding correct credentials for login.

please help

Here the code:

```
import { PayPal, PayPalPayment, PayPalConfiguration } from '@ionic-native/paypal';



  payWithPaypal(){
    //let amount = parseFloat(HomePage.orderinfo.total);
    this.payPal.init({
      PayPalEnvironmentProduction: 'AdXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: 'YOUR KEY'
    }).then(() => {
      this.payPal.prepareToRender('PayPalEnvironmentProduction', new PayPalConfiguration({
      })).then(() => {
        let payment = new PayPalPayment(this.paymentAmount, this.currency, 'description', 'sale');
        this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then((res) => {
           this.online('PAYPAL',res.response.id);
           this.responseData = JSON.stringify(res, null, 1);

          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'La orden ha sido agregada',
            subTitle: "El id de su gestion es: " + res.order_number,
            buttons: [{
                      text: "OK",
                      handler: () => {
                        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
                        this.navCtrl.push(OrderConfirmPage,{ OrderId: this.responseData.success });
                      }
                    }]
          });
          alert.present();
        }, (err) => {
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Error intentando conectar',
            subTitle: err,
            buttons: ['Dismiss']
          });
          alert.present();

        });
      }, (err) => {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Error con la configuracion',
          subTitle: err,
          buttons: ['Dismiss']
        });
        alert.present();
      });
    }, (err) => {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error con el plugin de PayPal',
        subTitle: err,
        buttons: ['Dismiss']
      });
      alert.present();
    });
  }
```

This is the screen capture

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Need more technical specifics about the error received and credentials used

Comment: @PrestonPHX, Is for PayPalEnvironmentProduction not for sandbox, not show any error, just cant login. I added a screen capture. Sometimes can login with my personal account, but when I tried with another one like my wife account or the another person always show me that alert